How to implement an screen updating switch off for Outlook (vsto add-in)?
While processing mailItems, an add-in opens and closes the mailitems and creates a visual pollution. As far as I found out there is now such method for Outlook. I tried:
newItem.Display(false);

newItem.GetInspector.WindowState = OlWindowState.olMinimized;

These methods don't give a result like a screenUpdating in Excel.
Maybe there is any trick to switch off screen updating?

Why woudl you want to display the messages if the user is not supposed to see them?

I had supposed that Display(false) doesn't show the message, but it opens and closes the message and create a visual pollution.  So I deleted it, and everything is OK now.

The method Display(false) opens mailitem and then closes it, that's why creates a visual pollution. There is no need to use this method to prevent open the mailitem.
